# Can I use the coalesce operator on integers to chain CompareTo?

Tags: c#, coalesce

I want to do something like this:

```
public override int CompareTo (Foo rhs)
{
    return Bar.CompareTo(rhs.Bar) ??
           Baz.CompareTo(rhs.Baz) ??
           Fuz.CompareTo(rhs.Fuz) ?? 0;
}
```

This doesn't work as written; is there some minimal workaround to make it work? Basically I want 0 to chain until non-zero (or end of chain).

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but if three values can be used to determine the return value, you might want to consider redesigning your class.

Comment: @DJ `CompareTo` is related to sorting; that is pretty common, actually - for example, sort by Surname - if that is the same, then sort by FirstName, then if still equal, sort by some unique identifier (database id, for example).

Comment: Are the methods `CompareTo` returning null? `??` is only working with null.

Comment: @Marc Interesting, I haven't been exposed to this before. I see that CompareTo is part of the IComparable class.  I'll have to read more to get some perspective. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not supported by the language. But you can write a small helper like this:

```
public override int CompareTo (Foo rhs)
{
    return FirstNonZeroValue(
        () => Bar.CompareTo(rhs.Bar), 
        () => Baz.CompareTo(rhs.Baz),
        () => Fuz.CompareTo(rhs.Fuz));
}

private int FirstNonZeroValue(params Func<int>[] comparisons)
{
    return comparisons.Select(x => x()).FirstOrDefault(x => x != 0);
}
```

Comment: Ugh. Solutions like this illustrate how much it sucks that we can't have global functions.

Comment: One could always put it in an extension function if used much, etc.

Comment: An extension on what? Int32? Is that even possible?

Comment: You can do it on int, wouldn't recommend it though. You could do it on `IComparable` to allow code like `this.FirstNonZeroValue( ... )`, or on `IEnumerable<Func<int>>` (but then you loose the niceness of niceness of having the `params` parameter list.

Comment: Ah, I didn't think of doing it on the interface. That's nice!

Answer (score 2):

No basically, but it would be nice if it did (IIRC, Jon mentioned a similar idea in C# in Depth). You could probably chain *conditionals*, but I tend to just use:

```
int delta = Bar.CompareTo(rhs.Bar);
if(delta == 0) delta = Baz.CompareTo(rhs.Baz);
if(delta == 0) delta = Fuz.CompareTo(rhs.Fuz);
return delta;
```

Answer (score 2):

Not really, `??` only works for null values (reference types or nullable structs)

```
int i;

i = Bar.CompareTo(rhs.Bar);
if (i != 0) return i;

i = Baz.CompareTo(rhs.Baz);
if (i != 0) return i;

i = Fuz.CompareTo(rhs.Fuz);
if (i != 0) return i;

return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

If short-circuiting is not needed, you can do some binary arithmetic.  [It is not required that the Compare results must be -1, 0, or 1, but that they must be < 0, = 0, > 0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfakywbh(v=vs.110).aspx).  So by using 2^n as a coefficient where n is the precedence, you can sum up the CompareTo results and get a number >0 or <0 as needed.

So, use

```
return 4 * Bar.CompareTo(rhs.Bar)
     + 2 * Baz.CompareTo(rhs.Baz)
     + 1 * Fuz.CompareTo(rhs.Fuz);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also change zero to null with a function and get lazy evaluation without `Func<>` :

```
public override int CompareTo (Foo rhs) =>
    Bar.CompareTo(rhs.Bar).GetNullIfZero() ??
    Baz.CompareTo(rhs.Baz).GetNullIfZero() ??
    Fuz.CompareTo(rhs.Fuz);

public static class IntExtensions
{
    public static int? GetNullIfZero(this int i) => i == 0 ? null : (int?)i;
}
```

There's a similar way for lazy chaining string operations with a `GetNullIfEmpty` and `GetNullIfWhiteSpace` extensions.